# Create a column that ranges between two rows in an ordered dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data-manipulation, zoo

So I have some GPS data, where the devices turns on and logs the duration of an event whenever said event occurs. At the end of the event, it then takes one to two GPS fixes of where it occurred, unless interrupted. To use the data I need to associate each event with a unique ID, so that I can then calculate some summaries:

[image: data structure I have]

Essentially, what I need to do is add a column to the dataframe which associates each event with a unique ID number like so:

[image: data structure I need]

As shown above, I want to assign a ascending number to each event that runs between the `"event_start"` through to the associated `GPS_fix` - which can be one or two. However, some of the events are interrupted (`"event_endint"` instead of `"event_end"`) meaning that ***either*** no fixes could not be collected ***or*** just one fix was established. In the case of no fixes, the numbering of the `event_id` would just continue on until the next `GPS_fix`. In the case of one fix, it would get it's own unique ID which extends to the GPS row, and in the event of two fixes, it would extend to both GPS fix rows.

Note, it would be great if the code were `dplyr` friendly, as I have multiple GPS units and I will need to distinguish between them. Ultimately, I am going to be calculating summaries and I intend to do that using `dplyr`/`tidyr`

Below is some example data

```
df <- structure(list(date = c("1/01/2000", "1/01/2000", "1/01/2000", 
"1/01/2000", "1/01/2000", "1/01/2000", "1/01/2000", "1/01/2000", 
"2/01/2000", "2/01/2000", "2/01/2000", "2/01/2000", "3/01/2000", 
"3/01/2000", "3/01/2000", "5/01/2000", "5/01/2000", "5/01/2000", 
"5/01/2000", "5/01/2000", "5/01/2000", "5/01/2000", "5/01/2000", 
"5/01/2000", "5/01/2000", "5/01/2000", "5/01/2000", "5/01/2000", 
"5/01/2000"), time = c("1:00", "2:00", "3:00", "4:00", "5:00", 
"6:00", "6:01", "6:02", "20:00", "21:00", "22:00", "23:00", "0:00", 
"1:00", "6:01", "14:00", "15:00", "16:00", "17:00", "18:00", 
"19:00", "14:00", "15:00", "16:00", "17:00", "18:00", "19:00", 
"19:01:00 am", "19:02:00 am"), datatype = c("event_start", "event", 
"event", "event", "event", "event_end", "GPS_fix", "GPS_fix", 
"event_start", "event", "event", "event", "event", "event_endint", 
"GPS_fix", "event_start", "event", "event", "event", "event", 
"event_endint", "event_start", "event", "event", "event", "event", 
"event_end", "GPS_fix", "GPS_fix"), lat = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 42.1, 42.05, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 43.1, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 50, 50), long = c(NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 180.1, 180.1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 181, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 170, 170)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-29L))
```

I have had a crack at coding it using the `zoo` package but I honestly can't figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use a condition to check whether the `datatype` is equal to "event_start", and at the same time the previous row does not equal "event_endint", then `cumsum` the logical values.

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(event_id = cumsum(grepl("event_start", datatype) & lag(datatype, default = first(datatype)) != "event_endint"))

        date        time     datatype   lat  long event_id
1  1/01/2000        1:00  event_start    NA    NA        1
2  1/01/2000        2:00        event    NA    NA        1
3  1/01/2000        3:00        event    NA    NA        1
4  1/01/2000        4:00        event    NA    NA        1
5  1/01/2000        5:00        event    NA    NA        1
6  1/01/2000        6:00    event_end    NA    NA        1
7  1/01/2000        6:01      GPS_fix 42.10 180.1        1
8  1/01/2000        6:02      GPS_fix 42.05 180.1        1
9  2/01/2000       20:00  event_start    NA    NA        2
10 2/01/2000       21:00        event    NA    NA        2
11 2/01/2000       22:00        event    NA    NA        2
12 2/01/2000       23:00        event    NA    NA        2
13 3/01/2000        0:00        event    NA    NA        2
14 3/01/2000        1:00 event_endint    NA    NA        2
15 3/01/2000        6:01      GPS_fix 43.10 181.0        2
16 5/01/2000       14:00  event_start    NA    NA        3
17 5/01/2000       15:00        event    NA    NA        3
18 5/01/2000       16:00        event    NA    NA        3
19 5/01/2000       17:00        event    NA    NA        3
20 5/01/2000       18:00        event    NA    NA        3
21 5/01/2000       19:00 event_endint    NA    NA        3
22 5/01/2000       14:00  event_start    NA    NA        3
23 5/01/2000       15:00        event    NA    NA        3
24 5/01/2000       16:00        event    NA    NA        3
25 5/01/2000       17:00        event    NA    NA        3
26 5/01/2000       18:00        event    NA    NA        3
27 5/01/2000       19:00    event_end    NA    NA        3
28 5/01/2000 19:01:00 am      GPS_fix 50.00 170.0        3
29 5/01/2000 19:02:00 am      GPS_fix 50.00 170.0        3
```